# Cast a type to the same type but in different assembly?

Tags: c#

I serialized a class and sent it to another application using `IPC`, however when i try to cast the received class to the same class (but in different assembly) i always get null if (in case of safe cast) or throw exception if direct cast..

So how can i access data members of the received class throw `IPC` ? note i use `JSON` Serialize and De-serialize to send my class to the other application.

I tried setting both applications with the same assembly name but this doesn't work.

Also i tried setting the Assembly GUID with the same result.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte) out and apply the reversed logic to convert it back from bytes to an object.

Comment: @YoryeNathan it is not byte it is Json object as i stated i use JSON.net to serialize and deserialize the object

Comment: If you have same class name in different assemblies then they are two different types even if the have same name. Make a common assembly and using on both serialization and de-serialization end.

Comment: because binary needs a lot of edits to the existing code, JSON.NET seems to work very nicely however it doesn't cast the received objects to their equivelants in the target assembly

Comment: Everything is made out of bytes. If you already have a different serialization/deserialization method (e.g JSON), that's just as good. Include your code to show where the actual problem is.

Comment: Also see solutions from: [InvalidCastException for two Objects of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2500280/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

If you have same class name in different assemblies then they are two different types even if the have same name. Make a common assembly and using on both serialization and de-serialization end.

If you do not want to have a common assembly which is recommended way, you can get the serialized json string and get the properties and values from this string and use them to create the object you want.

I used [JSON.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/598599) to convert the json string to dictionary to access the properties with values. You can more way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net).

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonSerializedString);
MyObject myObject = new MyObject { Name = dic["Name"], Id = int.Parse(dic["Id"]) };
```

I used MyObject which would be replaced by your type

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't confuse `different assembly` with `different namespace`.

If this is really the **same** class you should have it in a namespace which is visible/accessible by both sides. Try to put your class in a common assembly which is referenced on both sides.

If you can't change the assembly structure define an **interface** (in an additional assembly) which can be referenced by both sides. On the receiving side you may declare a new class which implements this interface.

Comment: so there is no way i can convert it on the fly, because doing so will require me to alter alot of the core code.

Comment: I don't understand how your first statement, "Don't confuse different assembly with different namespace." applies here. The OP hasn't said anything about namespaces.

Comment: @Enigmativity he understands me

Comment: @DanielEugen Instead of type casting you can also create object of the class to which you want to type cast.

Comment: @Adil what you mean ?

Comment: I think, I could not explain in comment so posting answer, please have a look.