# When would using Assembly.LoadFrom or Assembly.LoadFile be appropriate?

Tags: c#

When would using Assembly.LoadFrom or Assembly.LoadFile be appropriate?

Comment: Have you read these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile.aspx? What did you understand? What didn't you understand?

Comment: Allready been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477843/difference-between-loadfile-and-loadfrom-with-net-assemblies Check it.

Comment: We need more context to answer a question like this. Which one is more appropriate depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Main difference is that `LoadFrom` can be redirected to another assembly at a different path but with same identity if it's already loaded. `LoadFile` just loads exactly what the caller requested.

So, you should use `LoadFrom` when you need to prevent loading second assembly with same identity or just loading assembly twice.

Respectively, you should use `LoadFile` only if you need to load assembly twice or load two assemblies with same identifier.

You can read more in this article [LoadFile vs LoadFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/suzcook/loadfile-vs-loadfrom).