# Error creating a page (XAML) at runtime from an assembly in WinUi (desktop)

Tags: c#, xaml, plugins, reflection, winui-3

I have two projects for WinUI 3 (Desktop). One project is a desktop app and the other project is a class library (for desktop app). In the library I would like to define a page in XAML and load it into the desktop app at runtime (plug-in concept). The library is called 'MyHome.dll'. A page is defined there in XAML. The class for the page is called 'MyHome'.

The code for loading the assembly:

```
var dir = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
Assembly MyHomeAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile (dir + "/MyHome.dll");
var page = (Page) Assembly.CreateInstance ("MyHome.MyHome")
```

The assembly is loaded. With the debugger I can see that the class 'MyHome' is included. A XAML parsing error is generated.
My question: How do I load a Page (XAML) and the code C #) from a class at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method `Assembly.LoadFrom()` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile()`

This post describes the difference between this two methods:
[Difference between LoadFile and LoadFrom with .NET Assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477843/difference-between-loadfile-and-loadfrom-with-net-assemblies)

Here is a simple example for the plug and play method to load modules on runtime.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. The XAML parse error persists. Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: No, I am sorry. You can import the XAML-File in a "fresh"/new WPF project to check if it works there. If the parse error persists you know that the issue is comming from the file and not from the loading process.

Answer (score 0):

The error continues. The code of Desktop-App:

```
private void LoadAssemblys()
        {
            var dir = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            Assembly MyHomeAssembly=Assembly.LoadFrom(dir + "/MyHome.dll");
            System.Type[] types = MyHomeAssembly.GetTypes();
            System.Type primaryTyp = types[0];
            foreach (System.Type t in types)
            {
                if (t.Name == "MyHomePage")
                {
                     var obj = MyHomeAssembly.CreateInstance("MyHome.MyHomePage", true);
                }
            }
        }
```

The dll is an simple class-library-Project with xaml-Code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyHome.MyHomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MyHome"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The error:
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: "XAML"